# What "Additional CSS" Should I insert into WordPress to set default font to Proxima Nova?

Tags: wordpress

This is my first time building a website on my own and I am having a hard time trying to find the wording of code to set it as default for the whole site.

Comment: If the font is already included in the site you can add `body { font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif; }` to your stylesheet to set it as the body font (if that is the actual font name.) If the theme has `font-family` set for headings and paragraphs, you will have to change those individually or set the `!important` flag on the `body {}` style.

Comment: You need to go through your css file(s) and look for all font-family tags and alter that to the font you want. Do as Ty says and add the body tag to catch all cases of a default font being used. But you also need to make sure there is a delivery system for people who don't have the font currently installed on their machines.